# Having trouble with the xpath syntax for retrieving img src attribute using Python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml, elementtree

I've been trying to figure out the xpath syntax to parse this html, but I haven't been getting the same results as others. I've been modeling my work after, http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/#web-scraping, but I can't get it to work for my html.

```
<div id="sku-8103">
    <!-- B:649 -->
    <input type="hidden" id="productIdPDP" value="1218866963585"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="skuIdPDP" value="8240103" />
    <input type="hidden" id="enableLightbox" value="" />
    <!-- B:780 -->
    <img src="http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/en_US/images/global/buttons/btn_notorderable_pdp.gif" alt="Not Orderable" border="0" id="notorderable" />
    <input name="8240103" type="hidden" value="1">
    <!-- E:780 -->
    <!-- E:649 -->
    </div>
```

My Code:

```
import pycurl
import sys
import cStringIO
from lxml import etree
from lxml import html

buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://www.bestbuy.com/site/sony-playstation-4-500gb/8240103.p?id=1218866963585&skuId=8240103')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
c.perform()

data = buf.getvalue()
buf.close()

tree = html.fromstring(data)


product = tree.xpath('//div[@id="sku-8240103"]/img[@src]')
print product
```

The output is: `[]` instead of the `src` value of the image. I also tried:

```
product = tree.xpath('//div[@id="sku-8240103"]/img[@src]/text()')
```

but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML has this:

```
<div id="sku-8103">
```

You're searching with this:

```
product = tree.xpath('//div[@id="sku-8240103"]/img[@src]')
```

Notice the different SKU number? There are no matching nodes, and therefore you get back the empty list, `[]`.

If you change it like this:

```
product = tree.xpath('//div[@id="sku-8103"]/img[@src]')
```

You now get a single-element list, like this:

```
[<Element img at 0x10c85b890>]
```

And if you do this:

```
print product[0].attrib['src']
```

… you get this:

```
http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/en_US/images/global/buttons/btn_notorderable_pdp.gif
```

Really, you don't need the `[@src]` part there; if you're attempting to restrict it to `img`s that have a `src` attribute… what other `img`s do you expect to see?

Comment: Good catch! ...but that was just a typo for my post. However, it looks like print(product[0].attrib['src']) does work, instead of just print product. Do you know why print product doesnt work? Isn't it just a list?

Comment: @user1152532: It _does_ work. You see that `[<Element img at 0x10c85b890>]`? That's the output that I copied and pasted from running the last three lines of your code, with the SKU fixed, against your data. It's a list with one img `Element` object in it.

Comment: @user1152532: If you're getting back an empty list, you must have some _other_ typo. Either that, or you somehow screwed up the HTML when copying it from the real page.

Comment: Right... I guess I'm curious as to why the `print products` didn't result in the full contents of the Element object. I'm used to working with JSON, and when I print the entire object, the child objects are printed as well.

Comment: @user1152532: When you print out a list in Python, it prints the `repr` of each thing in that list. Normally, types that have some string representation that's readable to humans and also usable as input to the interpreter will make that their `repr`, while types that don't will just give the default `repr`, which looks like `<Element img at 0x10c85b890>`.

Comment: @user1152532: Meanwhile, when you parse a JSON string, you don't get a "JSON object tree" or anything; you just get a Python `dict` full of Python `dict`s and `list`s and `str`s and so on. That's because JSON is specifically designed to only hold simple types that are common to all scripting languages. That's not true for HTML or XML.